# Why to use width if I use max-width?

Tags: html, css

I just learned it on a course and don't really understand the logic.
I have to set a width:100%; for a container, and then set a max-width:800px; so it will no go larger than that.

But why should I use width:100%; at all? I can only set max-width:800px; and it will do the exact same thing without a width:100%;

Comment: It's hard to tell without more context, but I'm guessing that the goal is to have the container take up 100% of the width of it's parent, except for on very wide screens maybe you want to stop it from growing wider than 800px.

Comment: Example: `{width: 30%; max-width: 300px}`. Element will be 300px (eg. image size is 300px, so it can't be wider) width in 900px+ resolution, 30% in smaller ones. Another one exmaple: `.container {width: 96%; max-width: 1600px; margin: auto}` - in big screens you want to have your container only 1600px wide, in smaller ones you want to have margin on screen edges (2% on right/left).

Comment: @pavel True, but I think he was referring to the specific case when it's 100% wide.

Comment: @F.Müller: Ah, okay... Maybe you're right, I've understood the question why to combine `width` and `max-width` in general.

Answer (score 2):

> I can only set max-width:800px; and it will do the exact same thing without a width:100%;

It will do the exactly the  same thing if available width which your element can expand is less than or equal to 800px.

If you provide width 100% and if the screen resolution is 1024px, your element will be of width 1024px provided you didnt mention `max-width`;

`max-width:800px` will restrict the width of your element to 800px. Which means your element will be always less than or equal to 800px even if there is room for expansion.

The behaviour also changes with block level and inline-block elements.

**Few examples with block level and inline-block elements**

```css
#one {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

#two {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#three {
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
}

#four {
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color: purple;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

div {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">width 100%; no max-width; block element</div>


<div id="two">width 100%;max-width: 300px; My width will be always less &lt;=300px; block level element</div>
<br />
<span>With display : inline-block without width:100%</span><br />
<div id="three">300px;</div>

<div>With display : inline-block with max-width:300px and width:100%</div>

<div id="four">300px;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

"if the element would render wider than the max-width says it should be, then the max-width property wins over the width property. But if it would render less than the max-width says, then the width property wins."

[Article link](https://blog.prototypr.io/what-even-is-the-difference-between-width-and-max-width-8f37b282c7f1?gi=4a4b1931acba#:%7E:text=This%20is%20a%20simple%20way,the%20browser%20use%20max%2Dwidth.)

Answer (score 0):

There may be case where the width of  the container is 700px so width:100%  & max- width:800px will pick the 700px width.
max-width we are using so that we can restrict it to specific width to 800px

Answer (score 0):

It will check that

If the container's width is less than or equal to 800px

then it will set the width to 100%

else if the container's width is greater than 800px then it will set the width to 800px

```js
setInterval(()=>{document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = `width of window = ${window.innerWidth} width of textarea is ${document.querySelector("div").style.width}`},100)
```

```css
div{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid black;
    resize: both;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

What I did there with javascript was only changing the text.

Because of in stackOverflow don't allow hanging width of the iframe, I did another code

```js
setInterval(()=>{document.querySelector("div#g").innerHTML = `width of container = ${document.querySelector("div").style.width}
},1)
```

```css
div{
    box-sizing: content-box;
    border: 2px solid black;
    resize: both;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow:auto;
    display: flex;
}
div#g{
    max-width: 500px;
        width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<div><div id="g"></div></div>
```

there are two resizable divs

try resizing the container and the div

if the container's width is lessthan or equal to 500px then it will set the innerDiv's width to fit the container or 100%

if the container's width is greater than 500px then the innerDiv will set its width to 500px

Click and drag on the resize icon on the bottom-right corner to resize the divs.

Click on the innerDiv's resize to get the width of it